# How do i specify same delay for all the iterations?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```css
.move
{
     background-image: url("http://placehold.it/100x100");
     width: 100%;
     height: 300px;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: 100% 100%;
     animation: move 1s ease 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes move
{
    from{background-position: 0, 0}
    to{background-position:200px,0}
}
```

```html
<div class="move"> </div>
```

You can see 3 seconds delay during the first time. i want the same delay for all the iterations. Is there any way to achieve this?

**EDIT**
   If its not possible with css3 animation, please let me know an alternative solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the delay inside the keyframes specifying the same properties for 2 time values

```css
.move
{
     background-image: url("http://placehold.it/100x100");
     width: 100%;
     height: 300px;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: 100% 100%;
     animation: move 4s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes move
{
    from {background-position: 0, 0}
    75% {background-position: 0, 0}
    to{background-position:200px,0}
}
```

```html
<div class="move"> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this. What could be the reason for downvoting?

Comment: Probably that it is considered a very easy question. But there are lots of equally easy questions that don't get downvoted ...

Comment: Thanks Man. I want to know how it works? I don't understand it. Please help me with this. I can understand at the 75th % of the animation, it ll retain at 0 0. Animation takes place at the last 25%. If i do the same for 25,50%, do i get more delay? Is it like this?

Comment: The delay is the flat part of the animation. If the total animation time is 4s, and you set the change point at 75%, that is 3s. If you want to change that to say, 5 seconds of pause and 1 of animation, the total is 6s (animation-duration. And 5 / 6 = 84% for the middle keyframe